# Why is JsonTypeInfo required if the context tells us the expected element

Tags: java, json, spring

I got a Product class, with 3 subclasses. the product class is annotated with

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Fries.class, name = "FRIES"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Meat.class, name = "MEAT"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Sauce.class, name = "SAUCE")})
public abstract class Product {...}
```

I got a Spring RestController, which has the following method:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Void> createSauce(@RequestBody Sauce sauce){
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}
```

I am using Chrome postman to create Sauces, and the following JSON is NOT working, with the exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for class domain.Sauce)`

```
{
    "name": "Hannibal",
    "saucePortion": "LARGE"
}
```

The following JSON is working:

```
{
    "name": "Hannibal",
    "saucePortion": "LARGE",
    "type": "SAUCE"
}
```

So why does Jackson need to know the type 'SAUCE', while he actually knows that the JSON will be mapped onto a requestbody of class Sauce?

I understand that an eventual method `createProduct(@RequestBody Product product)` would need this type, but why if you specify the subclass?

Comment: This issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/955) and, at the time of this writing, there's no proper solution for it. Since it's labeled as `2.9`, this issue may be addressed in the next version of Jackson.

Comment: So i'm searching for a solution that does not exist yet :( Thanks for your response Cassio

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. But you can try a custom serializer.